# How do I fix this javascript error that my noob butt has been trying to solve for three days?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lint

I am coding a website in react js. I keep running into this error when I push to my github.

> ```
> Run npm run lint
> npm run lint
> shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
>
> bs-todo@0.1.0 lint /home/runner/work/A1-Flickit/A1-Flickit
> eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx}
>
>
> /home/runner/work/A1-Flickit/A1-Flickit/src/components/Form.js
> ##[error]  130:57  error  Replace `Send` with `⏎················Send⏎··············`  prettier/prettier
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
>  1 error and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! bs-todo@0.1.0 lint: `eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx}`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the bs-todo@0.1.0 lint script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-08-17T02_58_10_523Z-debug.log
> ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running LINT (probably your app has eslint configured), and it throws erros when there is code out of the rules.

Try fix the problem on your Form component, on **130:57**:
error Replace Send with ⏎················Send⏎·············· prettier/prettier

Or you can also open your package.json, and change the Lint script adding the —fix option.